# How to prove that it is NP-complete?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, reductions, 3-sat

I was trying to do this exercise, but I don't know how to solve this problem is NP-complete, what reduction to do.

There is a network N of n people, in which every person i is associated with a subset of people Fi ⊆ N . For every i∈N, it holds that i∈Fi, and if person j is in Fi, then it must be that i is in Fj as well. Your goal is to advertise a product to every person in N. To do so, you need to choose a set of advertisers among N that will promote it, each will advertise it among his associates.
Prove that the problem of finding whether there exists a set of size at most k of advertisers that can promote your product, is NP-Complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).